# Coin Change Problem with Memoization

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, change-making-problem

### Purpose

Another take on the classic [Change-making Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem):

> Given some set of coins and a value, find the minimum number of coins necessary to add up to this value

In my implementation, instead of returning the number of coins, I'm returning a `Map` of the coin values and their
counts.

For example, given the coin values `[1, 5]`, we'd expect my implementation to return `{1: 2, 5: 1}` for an input of `7`.

### Implementation Details

I decided to memoize results from previous calculations so as to not redo the same work over and over again.
The idea here is that if an input value is greater than the size of the cache, we can use the cache to identify
all values between the current size of the cache and the input value itself.

For example, the initial cache size is `1` (index `0` is mapped to an empty `HashMap`). Let's say, I call
`calculateMinimumCoinChange` with `7`. Since the input value (`7`) is greater than the size of the cache (`1`),
empty `HashMap`s are mapped to index values `1` to `7`, inclusive.

Then, starting from the previous size index (`1`), I use the cache values to calculate the coin change counts
for index values `1` through `7`. Thus, the cache should now contain coin change counts from `0` through `7`.

So if I look up the coin change counts for `5`, I can just lookup the value in the cache. If I look up the coin change
counts for `10`, I would expand my cache and use the coin change counts from `0` through `7` to inform my counts for
`8` through `10`.

There are a few things about my implementation that give me pause.

1. I think it makes sense for the `CoinChangeCalculator` to take a `Set` of `Integer` coin values as an instance variable.
   But does it make sense to check this `Set` for `null`s or negative values in the constructor? Again, I think it does
   (obviously) but I'm open to alternative suggestions.
2. Is there a better way to implement my memoization?
3. I had a really tough time with naming, especially when talking about counts, so open to alternative naming suggestions.

### Implementation

```
package problems.impl;

import java.util.*;

public class CoinChangeCalculator {
    private final Set<Integer> coinValues;
    private final List<Map<Integer, Integer>> coinChangeCounts;

    public CoinChangeCalculator(Set<Integer> coinValues) {
        for (Integer coinValue : coinValues) {
            if (coinValue == null || coinValue < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Invalid coin value: {} ", coinValue));
            }
        }

        this.coinValues = coinValues;
        this.coinChangeCounts = new ArrayList<>();
        this.coinChangeCounts.add(0, new HashMap<>());
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> calculateMinimumCoinChange(int value) {
        if (value > this.coinChangeCounts.size()) {
            int previousSize = this.coinChangeCounts.size();

            for (int index = previousSize; index <= value; index++) {
                this.coinChangeCounts.add(index, new HashMap<>());
            }

            for (int subValue = previousSize; subValue <= value; subValue++) {
                for (Integer coinValue : this.coinValues) {
                    int previousValue = subValue - coinValue;
                    if (previousValue >= 0) {
                        Map<Integer, Integer> previousValueChangeChange = coinChangeCounts.get(previousValue);
                        Map<Integer, Integer> subValueChangeCounts = coinChangeCounts.get(subValue);

                        int previousCoinCounts = previousValueChangeChange.values().stream()
                                .filter((counts) -> counts != null)
                                .mapToInt(Number::intValue)
                                .sum();
                        int subValueCoinCounts = subValueChangeCounts.values().stream()
                                .filter((counts) -> counts != null)
                                .mapToInt(Number::intValue)
                                .sum();

                        if (subValueChangeCounts.isEmpty() || previousCoinCounts + 1 < subValueCoinCounts) {
                            Map<Integer, Integer> updatedChangeCounts = new HashMap<>(previousValueChangeChange);

                            Integer coinValueCount = updatedChangeCounts.get(coinValue);
                            if (coinValueCount == null) {
                                updatedChangeCounts.put(coinValue, 1);
                            } else {
                                updatedChangeCounts.put(coinValue, coinValueCount + 1);
                            }

                            coinChangeCounts.set(subValue, updatedChangeCounts);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return coinChangeCounts.get(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169874/make-change-for-a-given-amount-given-denominations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, I think your code is clear, well structured and easy to follow, and the variable names are informative. However, I found some flaws with it, which I will address first.

### Correcting (potential) bugs

- If an instance of `CoinChangeCalculator` is created with the constructor `CoinChangeCalculator(Set<Integer>)`, the created object will not have exclusive control over the field `coinValues`, because `coinValues` references the same object that was passed to the constructor, and since a `Set` is not immutable, something outside the object could modify the `Set<Integer>` referenced by `coinValues`, thereby corrupting your object. It would be safer to do this instead:

  ```java
  public CoinChangeCalculator(Set<Integer> coinValues) {
      // ...
      this.coinValues = new HashSet<>(coinValues);
      // ...
  }
  ```

  This will copy the `Integer`s from the passed `Set` into a new `HashSet`, and since an `Integer` is immutable, your object is now independent.
- There is a mistake in the first line inside the method `calculateMinimumCoinChange(int)`. The comparison should be:

  ```java
  if (value >= this.coinChangeCounts.size())
  ```

  Notice the `>=` operator instead of `>`. I assume this was a mistake, because the rest of your code looks like you're aware that the indexes in a `List` are zero-based.
- One can trick your algorithm into producing an erroneous result by including a coin with a value of `0` in the set of possible coins. If your inner `for` loop is on this 0-value-coin, then `previousValue` will equal `subValue`. However, your code seems to assume that `previousValue` is always less than `subValue` and that every element in `coinChangeCounts` with an index below `subValue` has a valid coin combination associated with it, so it will rely on `coinChangeCounts.get(previousValue)` to represent a correct coin combination. But if `coinValue == 0`, then `previousValue == subValue`, and `coinChangeCounts.get(previousValue)` will only contain the empty map you put there in the first `for` loop of the method, causing your code to fail. To prevent this, you can either disallow 0-value-coins in the first place, or you have to do an additional check when you enter the inner `for` loop. I would suggest prohibiting them in the first place, because if you do allow them and check if `coinValue > 0` when entering the inner `for` loop, the 0-value-coin will either never appear in a result, not even if you invoke `calculateMinimumCoinChange(0)`, or, if you set `coinChangeCounts.get(0)` to contain a mapping from `0` to `1` (i.e. one 0-value-coin) in the constructor, then the 0-value-coin will uselessly (and wrongly) appear in every other result as well. So it's probably easier just not to deal with this useless coin and let the constructor handle any attempt to confuse your code into malfunctioning.
- There is another bug in your code: The `for` loop that introduces `int subValue` will only update `coinChangeCounts` for that `subValue` index if there is at least one coin with a value that is smaller than or equal to `subValue`. However, if there is no coin with a value of 1, then not all coin combinations contained in `coinChangeCounts` will be valid for their respective indices. To rectify this problem, it is probably inevitable to use `Optional`s, or alternatively `null` values (although I would personally prefer the first, because it is explicit in its intention), to signify that a value has been positively determined to be impossible to construct using the available coins, as opposed to simply not being cached yet. Note that I've caught this bug after I had written most of the "Suggestions" section, so the examples there might not take this bug into account.

Following are some suggestions that are not corrections of mistakes, but possible ways to improve the code or its readability.

### Suggestions

- Populating `coinChangeCounts` with empty `HashMap`s for all indexes that do not yet contain a valid coin combination up to the queried value creates ambiguity about the contents of `coinChangeCounts` – it might not only contain a valid coin combination, but also empty `HashMap`s that don't represent a valid coin combination. This doesn't really help. True, it ensures that `coinChangeCounts.get(subValue)` returns a value, but what is this guarantee of being returned a value worth if you can't be sure that the returned value is of any use? `coinChangeCounts.get(int)` might as well not return any value at all if there is no associated coin combination for this index yet. That way, a 0-value-coin would have resulted in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` being thrown, which to me seems preferable to a wrong result being presented as an unexceptional outcome. So instead of filling up `coinChangeCounts` with empty `HashMap`s, you could do this inside the inner `for` loop:

  ```java
  // ...
  if (previousValue >= 0) {
      Map<Integer, Integer> previousValueChangeChange = coinChangeCounts.get(previousValue);
      int previousCoinCounts = previousValueChangeChange.values().stream()
              .filter((counts) -> counts != null)
              .mapToInt(Number::intValue)
              .sum();

      OptionalInt subValueCoinCounts;
      if (subValue < coinChangeCounts.size()) {
          subValueCoinCounts = OptionalInt.of(
                  coinChangeCounts
                          .get(subValue)
                          .values()
                          .stream()
                          .filter((counts) -> counts != null)
                          .mapToInt(Number::intValue)
                          .sum());
      } else {
          subValueCoinCounts = OptionalInt.empty();
      }

      if (!subValueCoinCounts.isPresent() || previousCoinCounts + 1 < subValueCoinCounts.getAsInt()) {
          // ...
          if (subValue < coinChangeCounts.size()) {
              coinChangeCounts.set(subValue, updatedChangeCounts);
          } else {
              coinChangeCounts.add(subValue, updatedChangeCounts);
              /* if I had used this instead of the one argument version
                 add(int) in the first place, I probably would have caught
                 the no-1-value-coin-bug sooner */
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Thus, the contract of `coinChangeCounts` can be that, for every index at which it contains an element, this element must be a valid coin combination for that index, which to me seems more practical than if an element could also be an empty map, because, as you have seen with the 0-value-coin, a bug can cause an empty map to be falsely interpreted as a valid coin combination.
- About the `null` checks in your code. You ask whether it makes sense to inspect the passed `Set<Integer>` for potential `null`s. In my opinion, it definitely does make sense. Catching unwanted `null` values trying to intrude into your methods/objects as early as possible can only be a good thing, because they can, at best, only cause just as much damage later on, if not more. I don't think it's different from checking if all integers are greater than (or equal to) zero. If the type of the parameter doesn't imply all the necessary conditions for it, then you have to check manually. The only alternative would be to create a custom implementation of `Set` that only accepts non-`null` and non-negative `Integer`s, and I doubt the benefits of such an approach would outweigh its impracticality.

  On the other hand, I think that `null`-checking when streaming over the values of `coinChangeCounts.get(previousValue)` and `coinChangeCounts.get(subValue)` is unnecessary, because `coinChangeCounts` is a `private` field and only you have control over its contents. And if you don't trust yourself and want to protect yourself from inadvertently putting a `null` value into one of the `Map`s in `coinChangeCounts`, you can always use assertions:

  ```java
  assert coinChangeCounts
          .get(previousValue)
          .values()
          .stream()
          .noneMatch(integer -> integer == null);
  ```

  In your case, `mapToInt(Number::intValue)` would throw a `NullPointerException` anyway if it encountered a `null` element, but this doesn't mean you can't explicitly check for `null`s if that is your intention (by the way, why don't you use `Integer::intValue` instead of `Number::intValue`? It doesn't make a difference in the end, but I find it a bit odd). Also, filtering out `null` elements would imply that a coin combination with a `null` value instead of a coin count is valid, so you're effectively passing up an opportunity to detect a bug in your program.