# Return the amount of Quarters, Dimes, Nickels, and Pennies that you would get from the total amount of change

Tags: c#, change-making-problem

I made windows form in C# that takes the amount of change given, 1-99 and tells you the amount of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies you would get back. Can I improve the math in any way? It takes the total change and subtracts the value of the largest coin value that applies till the change becomes equal to zero.

```
        //set the variables
        int quarters = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int nickels = 0;
        int pennies = 0;
        int change = Convert.ToInt32(txtChange.Text);

        //logic
        do
        {
            if (change >= 25 && change <= 99)
            {
                change = change - 25;
                quarters++;
            }
            else if (change <= 24 && change > 9)
            {
                change = change - 10;
                dimes++;
            }
            else if (change == 5)
            {
                change = change - 5;
                nickels++;
            }
            else if (change <=4)
            {
                change = change - 1;
                pennies++;
            }

            txtQuarters.Text = quarters.ToString("n");
            txtDimes.Text = dimes.ToString("n");
            txtNickels.Text = nickels.ToString("n");
            txtPennies.Text = pennies.ToString("n");

        } while (change > 0);
```

Comment: Why do you set the _text_ properties _inside_ your loop?

Comment: If you input `change` above 99, your loop never ends, by the way. If you check it beforehand, you don;t need o have it in your first `if`.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169874/make-change-for-a-given-amount-given-denominations

Comment: This fails on 6-9 and > 99.  Why print out every loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop only adds one coin to the change every repetition, which can be done faster: you don;t need the `else if`.

You don't want to set your `Text` properties inside your loop, but only when you're finished.

Also, you want to check if `change` > 99 before starting, otherwise your loop never ends.

Instead of

```
something = something + x;
```

you can use

```
something += x;
```

Once you're down to pennies, the number of pennies is your remaining change.

Instead of adding one coin every time, simply add all the quarters possible, then all the dimes, etcetera:

```
if (change > 99) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Too much change!");

while (change > 24)
{
    change -= 25;
    quarters++;
}
while (change > 9)
{
    change -= 10;
    dimes++;
}
while (change > 4)
{
    change -= 5;
    nickels++;
}

pennies = change;
```

Now, you can actually do away with all the loops very simply, by dividing the remaining change by the size of your next coin. The resulting *integer* is the amount of coins.

Then you get:

```
int quarters = change/25;
change -= quarters*25;
int dimes = change/10;
change -= dimes*10;
int nickels = change/5;
int pennies = change - nickels * 5;
```

Even shorter, using the % (modulo) operator:

```
int quarters = change/25;
change %= 25;
int dimes = change/10;
change %= 10;
int nickels = change/5;
int pennies = change%5;
```

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me out. Though, I'd have to make the loop change <= 99, because the change can be anywhere from 1 cent to 99 cents

Comment: @weisbeym Sure, even in the short version, I would keep the `if (change > 99) ` in there, though there is no loop necessary for that :)